# Change Background for whole bound row in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a datagrid in wpf project , using manual columns

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
<DataGridTextColumn   Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Society}"/>
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           ....
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want to change the background of the row depending on the bound data in each row,

any way to do it ?

Comment: Use IValueConverter, Background = "{Binding someData, Converter={StaticResource myCOnv}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change default `Style` for `DataGridCell` to set `Background` colour from bound property via custom [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that would convert your property value into `Brush`.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource ValueToColourConverter}}"/>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

or if you want to change `Background` only when that property has some specific value then you can use `Style.Triggers`:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}" Value="SomeValue">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Same thing what you need is already discussed in [DataGrid selection and conditional formatting](https://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/224402)...

It was generally say as *Conditional Formatting*.. you can either format the cell or a row based on some conditions..